# Get files from NAS in C#

Tags: c#, nas

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files from a NAS to my local PC.

I have a connection to the NAS but cant give it a Letter for reasons.

The path to my NAS looks something like this:

```
\\Some.domain@SSL@50005\DavWWWRoot\Folder
```

I can also use this

```
https://Some.domain:50005/Folder
```

Now I have run into the problem that

```
File.Exists("\\Some.domain@SSL@50005\DavWWWRoot\SomeFile");
```

works fine but

```
File.Copy("\\Some.domain@SSL@50005\DavWWWRoot\SomeFile", SomePath, true);
```

returns an error

> Illegal characters in path

I tried the same with the https path but that just doesn't find any file to begin with.

But I can download files like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Name", "Password");

byte[] data = client.DownloadData("https://Some.domain:50005/Folder/File");
File.WriteAllBytes(destination, data);
```

Now this works for single files but not folders.

So I wrote this code:

```
//Get Files of Directory  
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(\\Some.domain@SSL@50005\DavWWWRoot\Folder);
    
//Create folder on Local PC
Directory.CreateDirectory("Somepath\Folder");
    
foreach (string file in files)
{
   //Dont Copy open word file things
   if (!file.Contains("~$"))
   {
       yield return StartCoroutine(GetFile(command[0] + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), command[1] + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), client));
   }
}
```

But now `Path.GetFileName` also returns "Invalid Character".

My question is why is this stuff so inconsistent?

Note: I tried a lot for example using `IEnumerator` to space the download attempts. It's not necessary

Comment: Debugging might reveal which "Invalid Character" is the cause of this issue. (see:  [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fdebugger%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2022))

Comment: BTW: Is your NAS not accessible via SMB-protocol? SMB on a local network is easier than WebDav.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces).